# add numpy subarray to numpy array based on condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conditional-statements

I have a 2d numpy array and a 2d numpy subarray that I want to add to the original array based on a condition.
I know that you can add the 2d subarray to the array like this:

```
original_array[start_x:end_x, start_y:end_y] = sub_array
```

but I dont know how to efficiently add only values of the sub_array that are bigger than 0?

Example:

```
orginal_array = np.array([2,2],[2,2],[2,2],[2,2])
sub_array = np.array([0,0],[1,1],[0,1],[0,0])
expected_result = np.array([2,2], [1,1], [2,1], [2,2])
```

Comment: Please update the question with 1) an example of the array, 2) an example of the sub array and 3) an example of the expected output.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index based on the condition `>,< 0` and add the arrays.

```
orginal_array * (sub_array <= 0) + sub_array * (sub_array > 0)

array([[2, 2],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the `np.where` function as:

```
np.where(sub_array > 0, sub_array, original_array)
```

Output:

```
array([[2, 2], 
       [1, 1], 
       [2, 1], 
       [2, 2]])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try,

```
sub_array2 = np.select([sub_array>0],[sub_array])
original_array[start_x:end_x, start_y:end_y] = sub_array2
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work as expected. I want the values in the original array stay the same, if the values in the subarray are 0 or less than 0. Look at my updated question